# Python Import get mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' M2 Mac

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm newbie in python program. I use MacBook Pro M2, Mac Monterey 12.4 and visual studio to program. But every time I import Torchvision or numpy I always get message :

```
    import torchvision
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from torchvision import datasets
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .lsun import LSUN, LSUNClass
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/lsun.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 100, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
```

I have spent a lot of time to research but no solution is work.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70723757/arch-x86-64-and-arm64e-is-available-but-python3-is-saying-incompatible-architect

Comment: @Whizbuzzer I using "arch -arm64 python3 -m pip install lib_name". But is not work,  when I import Torchvision , I got the same error

Comment: Have you tried conda environment? Read this [docs](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html#using-vscode-with-anaconda-conda-python-or-environments) for details.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT I solved Import numpy but now it's happened with torchvision. I'm very confused!

Comment: @Marino Please add it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have installed the wrong package version. Please select the [appropriate version](https://pytorch.org/) according to your PC.

At the same time, the official recommendation is to use the [conda](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html#using-vscode-with-anaconda-conda-python-or-environments) environment.

Comment: error seem happened from Pillow. I don't know how to fix

Comment: @Marinom Can [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/436801/m1-mac-mach-o-file-but-is-an-incompatible-architecture-have-x86-64-need-a) help?