# Web3 python crypto cypher issue on M1 Mac

Tags: python, cryptography, solidity, apple-m1, web3py

When I try to build a blockchain transaction using Web3 on python, I'm getting an error that is apparently because I'm using an Apple Silicon computer (2020 M1 MacBook Pro). I'm following a popular Solidity, Blockchain, and Smart Contract course on YouTube and I'm unable to get it working. Could someone please help me out?

My code fails when I try to build a transaction.

The error message I get when I run my code is below:

```
(myvenv) leonkc@Leons-MacBook-Pro web3_py_simple_storage % python deploy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/leonkc/solidityDemo/web3_py_simple_storage/deploy.py", line 3, in \<module\>
from web3 import Web3
File "/Users/leonkc/solidityDemo/web3_py_simple_storage/myvenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/__init__.py", line 6, in \<module\>
from eth_account import (
File "/Users/leonkc/solidityDemo/web3_py_simple_storage/myvenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eth_account/__init__.py", line 1, in \<module\>
from eth_account.account import (
File "/Users/leonkc/solidityDemo/web3_py_simple_storage/myvenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eth_account/account.py", line 11, in \<module\>
from eth_keyfile import (
File "/Users/leonkc/solidityDemo/web3_py_simple_storage/myvenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eth_keyfile/__init__.py", line 7, in \<module\>
from eth_keyfile.keyfile import (  # noqa: F401
File "/Users/leonkc/solidityDemo/web3_py_simple_storage/myvenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eth_keyfile/keyfile.py", line 6, in \<module\>
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
File "/Users/leonkc/solidityDemo/web3_py_simple_storage/myvenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/__init__.py", line 27, in \<module\>
from Crypto.Cipher.\_mode_ecb import \_create_ecb_cipher
File "/Users/leonkc/solidityDemo/web3_py_simple_storage/myvenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/\_mode_ecb.py", line 35, in \<module\>
raw_ecb_lib = load_pycryptodome_raw_lib("Crypto.Cipher.\_raw_ecb", """
File "/Users/leonkc/solidityDemo/web3_py_simple_storage/myvenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Crypto/Util/\_raw_api.py", line 309, in load_pycryptodome_raw_lib
raise OSError("Cannot load native module '%s': %s" % (name, ", ".join(attempts)))
OSError: Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Cipher.\_raw_ecb': Not found '\_raw_ecb.cpython-39-darwin.so', Cannot load '\_raw_ecb.abi3.so': dlopen(/Users/leonkc/solidityDemo/web3_py_simple_storage/myvenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Crypto/Util/../Cipher/\_raw_ecb.abi3.so, 0x0006): tried: '/Users/leonkc/solidityDemo/web3_py_simple_storage/myvenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Crypto/Util/../Cipher/\_raw_ecb.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e))), '/Users/leonkc/solidityDemo/web3_py_simple_storage/myvenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/\_raw_ecb.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e))), Not found '\_raw_ecb.so'
```

I've tried reinstalling pycryptodome as per another Stack Overflow answer but I still get the same error (with `pip install pycryptodome --no-cache-dir --verbose --force-reinstall` )

I'm using a Ganache Ethereum blockchain with an unimportant test address.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Try using `--no-binary` in your `pip install` to force compiling from source.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Thom, but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I finally ended up fixing this. It was a combination of *jeugregg*'s suggestion here and *luchanos*'s solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70723757/arch-x86-64-and-arm64e-is-available-but-python3-is-saying-incompatible-architect).

That is to say, the things that finally made it work for me were:

- Downloading Python 3.9.5 from https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/
  with "Download macOS 64-bit universal2 installer"
- Use `python3-intel64` command to run Python instead of just `python`
- Create new venv in project from the base interpreter that you installed
- Install all requirements to venv
- Uninstall pycryptodome with pip (I think I had to do `pip uninstall pycryptodome` twice) and reinstalling with `conda install pycryptodome` **(crucial step)**
- If I recall correctly I had to do similar reinstallations with a few other libraries (e.g. cytoolz, bitarray), which came up as errors when trying to install eth-brownie and which I addressed ad-hoc, but this may not be a problem for you
- `pipx install eth-brownie=1.14.6`

Python 3.9.5 and brownie version 1.14.6 seem to be the best combination.

Answer (score 1):

I have almost the same issue.
It is very strange but, I manage to use web3 "Crypto.Cipher._raw_ecb" lib by reinstall some libs.
I explain.
To manage virtual environment, I use miniforge (https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge).
From a new fresh env : `conda create --name envTest python=3.10`
I install `web3` with `pip` (because no osx-arm64 build in conda):
`pip install web3 --no-cache-dir --verbose --force-reinstall`
After I reinstalled conda version of 2 libs :
`pip uninstall pycryptodome`  (v3.16.0)
`conda install pycryptodome` (v3.15.0)
`pip uninstall lru-dict`  (v1.1.8)
`conda install lru-dict` (v1.1.8)

For the moment, it works for me.
I think it is not a final solution.
You can try.

If something gone wrong with conda, because it just use cache and don't take the new fresh builds, use this command : `conda clean -p` : purge all packages caches on your local storage.

Comment: Thank you for this jeugregg, I have since got it working using a similar solution (reinstalling pycryptodome with conda). Really appreciate the answer, and you reminded me that I have this post still up. I've posted my answer below.