# M1 Mac - PyCharm - Unable to run on arm64

Tags: python, pycharm, apple-m1, arm64

It appears I'm unable to run the arm64 architecture in PyCharm and I don't understand why. I would really like to learn what I'm doing wrong.

**Specs**
I'm on a 2021 M1 MacBook Pro with macOs Monterey 12.6.2

PyCharm 2022.3.2 (Community Edition)
Runtime version: 17.0.5+1-b653.25 aarch64

For my virtual environments I use conda (miniforge3) version 4.14.0

When I run 'uname -m' in the PyCharm terminal it returns 'x86_64', however when I run the same command in zsh terminal I get 'arm64'. Both are executed in the conda 'base' environment and I would have expected the architectures to be the same.

**What I've done**

- Downloaded PyCharm aarch64 (I was previously on x86_64), yielded the same result
- Create specific arm64 and x86_64 conda environments, all return x86_64
- Followed the steps in this thread [arch x86_64 and arm64e is available but python3 is saying incompatible architecture on Mac M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70723757/arch-x86-64-and-arm64e-is-available-but-python3-is-saying-incompatible-architect)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: My `uname -a` in PyCharm gives me `22.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.1.0: Sun Oct  9 20:15:09 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8792.41.9~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64 arm Darwin`

Comment: For me it returns Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Sun Nov  6 23:31:13 PST 2022; root:xnu-8020.240.14~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved by deleting the current version of PyCharm and removing the left over ID directories as explained here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#logs-directory

After re-installing PyCharm it now works!